# The width of a table row changes after I collapse and expand it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Javascript and CSS, I try to expand/collapse table rows using JavaScript.

And, I use CSS to change the style of my tables.

Here comes my code snippet:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function ShowSubTable(titleRow)
            {    
                var nextRow = titleRow.nextSibling;
                while (nextRow != null)
                {
                    if( nextRow.tagName != 'TR' ){
                        nextRow = nextRow.nextSibling;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (nextRow.style.display == 'none')
                    {
                        nextRow.style.display = 'block';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nextRow.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    break;
                }        
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            table.tlb
            {
                width: 100%;
            }
            table.tlb th
            {
                background: #E8C993;
                font-size: 22px;
            }
            table.tlb td
            {
                background: #FFEAAF;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="tlb">
            <tr onclick="ShowSubTable(this)">
                <th>abc</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr onclick="ShowSubTable(this)">
                <th>def</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>456</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The expand/collapse function works fine. But there is a problem.

The width of my table is 100% at the beginning. However, after I collapse a table row and expand it. the width of the table row is not 100%.

How to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should just restore the default display value when you show `tr` elements

```
nextRow.style.display = 'table-row';
```

instead of

```
nextRow.style.display = 'block';
```